# Likert Scale - Statistical Analysis?

Tags: anova, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, likert, kruskal-wallis-test

I have conducted a very large survey (n>10,000). I asked all participants a series of demographic questions (gender, ethnicity, educational background etc - all categorical). I then asked all participants further questions where again all is categorical, for example "what will you do? a, b, c, d, e (1)

Afterwards,I ask all participants a series of 15 items in a Likert Scale format, from "Not at all Important" to "Very Important" (5 options). (2)

My goal is to carry out a sub analysis to see if there is a trend within demographic subgroups for both (1) and (2). Forgive me if I sound ignorant but I was thinking that for (1) a simple chi-squared is sufficient? I know that shows whether there is a significant relationship but is there anyway of finding the correlation between 2 categorical variables?

For (2), I have searched extensively and come up with ANOVA, Kruskal Wallis, Mann-Whitney etc. What should I use? And is there an example anywhere?

Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it